# How to return all documents when list of keywords is empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to query my database with a list of keywords with the results being ANDed.

This is the query I'm currently using:

```
SKU.find({name: {$all: keywords}}).exec()
```

This works as expected when there are 1 or more keywords. However when there are 0 keywords the query returns nothing. I would like for it to return all the documents in the database.

Comment: I think this can be done at application level. If the size of keywords is zero, you may better do a simple find() and paginate the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this on the node side itself.

Something like,

```
if (keywords.length > 0) {
    filterCriterion = { name: { $all: keywords } }
} else {
    filterCriterion = {}
}

SKU.find(filterCriterion).exec()
```